# Import custom library outside the root directory in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I try to import (in Brocfile.js) custom library outside the root directory.
I wrote path like this `app.import("./../../../public/scripts/js-helpers.js");` but ember-cli copy folder public into their working folder. What's wrong and how I can import this kind of libs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, but try putting js-helpers.js outside your public directory (e.g., your vendor directory) and importing from there.

Brocfile.js

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

var app = new EmberApp();

app.import('vendor/scripts/js-helpers.js');

module.exports = app.toTree();
```

Comment: Files from `vendor` loading very good. I have two different applications with one shared file which located not in `ember-cli` folder.